# MS Access Create a Query that Duplicates Data for Each Item in Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query in MS Access that duplicates data for every item in another table. The easiest way to explain is an example. Say I am an English teacher. I have 100 students in a table by name. I have another table of 50 assignments that need to be completed. How can I create a query that will duplicate ALL assignments for ALL students.

**Table1**

*Students*

```
1  Billy Bob
2  Anne Smith
```

**Table2**

```
*Assignments*      <>     *Assigned*    <>   *Due*
1  Homework 1 of 30  <>  1/1/1800   <>   1/15/1800
2  Quiz 1 of 15   <>     2/15/1800  <>   2/15/1800
3  Test 1 of 5    <>     3/20/1800  <>   3/20/1800
```

**Desired Result**

```
Billy Bob <> Homework 1 of 30  <>  1/1/1800   <>   1/15/1800 
Billy Bob <> Quiz 1 of 15    <>    2/15/1800  <>   2/15/1800
Billy Bob <> Test 1 of 5     <>    3/20/1800  <>   3/20/1800  
Anne Smith <> Homework 1 of 30 <>   1/1/1800  <>    1/15/1800 
Anne Smith <> Quiz 1 of 15     <>   2/15/1800 <>    2/15/1800
Anne Smith <> Test 1 of 5      <>   3/20/1800 <>    3/20/1800
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper SQL operation is called `CROSS JOIN`.  However, MS Access doesn't support this, preferring the `,` operator instead.  SO you can do:

```
select . . .
from students,  -- CROSS JOIN
     assignments;
```

The `. . .` is for the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact names of your tables or columns, but do it like this:

```
SELECT Students.Name, Assignments.Assignments, Assignments.Assigned,Assignments.Due
FROM students, assignments;
```

Comment: The join query worked. I even created a secondary query to filter the join. A query of a query. Now I can run a query to see who is late on assignments. You are all so helpful. Thank you